# Find the header row element in table whose th cells have a class called 'headerClass'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html and I would like to get the row element using jQuery, by using the fact that all th cells within this header row element have a fixed class of 'headerClass'.

**What will be the jQuery selector to get such a row?**

```
<tr>
  <th class="headerClass">Header1</th>
  <th class="headerClass">Header2</th>
  <th class="headerClass">Header3</th>
  <th class="headerClass">Header4</th>
  <th class="headerClass">Header5</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: A th cannot contain td elements (unless those tds are in an inner table of their own). A th is a cell, not a row. You probably meant to have a thead with a tr containing only th elements.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you get the row only when *all* of its cells have that class, i.e. none of its cells *don't* have that class, you will need to use a combination of `:not()` and `:has()`:

```
$('tr:not(:has(th:not(.headerClass)))')
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/qK8A2)

In case the selector notation above is too confusing, the following works identically:

```
$('tr').not(':has(th:not(.headerClass))')
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/qK8A2/1)

Comment: Wow, that was very nice. I would never have guessed that. Thanks for the brilliant answer.